# Wingpanel Disappeared

Tags: wingpanel

My wingpanel has just disappeared and despite searching the internet for answers, I cannot get it back.

It disappeared while I was working on configuring the networking to run a specific DNS setting.

I can confirm a few items: it is installed in the software center.  Whey I use the command line to "start" it, I get the error "Segmentation fault" - I've tried repairing it as well as uninstalling and reinstalling.

I am fairly new to ElementaryOS, so I apologize in advance for any lack of understanding.

Comment: What steps are you using to "start" it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry the late response.  I eneded up restoring an image from a few days prior.  I tried several things, but I am pretty good about backing up, so decided to go with that option.  I used Clonezilla, so just reimaged the drive and went forward from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing Super+Space (Or Win+Space) to force it back, worked for me.

Keep pressing it if it doesn't stick, because it will eventually.